# Image processing to pick out sky pixels

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have 72 tree canopy photos. I need a way of quantifying the "sky" pixels OR vegetation pixels to get a proportion of sky to tree canopy. This will give me an estimate of "canopy closure" on tree plantation plots after 25 years.

[image: sample canopy photo]

above is a screenshot of a canopy section. It would need to differentiate "sky" pixels from "tree" pixels to get a proportion of "canopy closure".

I am familiar with R at an intro level. I have never coded python before directly.. any suggestions?

Cheers,,

Comment: please review: [ask], [mre] (at the _very least_ you should have added a picture to your post)

Comment: Thank you Christoph. I appreciate your feedback I will review these in details. Cheers!

Comment: based on _that picture_, you could get a mask of *blue* pixels, and count/sum that to get a ratio. OpenCV: cvtColor to HSV, inRange on blue hues, good saturation, good value

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a *mask* of *blue sky*-colored pixels and then calculate the ratio of it.

[image: mask]

This is 33.6% sky (white).

Blue sky is nice and easy because it's got color. Overcast would be less ideal but still workable. For that you'd be left with brightness.

This is not terribly "scientific". My thresholds here are pulled out of a hat, which can be described as "empirically chosen". And you've got pictures, which aren't measurements. Pictures can have their information distorted arbitrarily (by the camera and whatever else postprocessing) to look pleasing.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("D:\\rEBeX.png")
hsv = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# select blue sky (this picture: ~215-220 degrees, saturation >25%, value near 100%)
# opencv, for uint8 data, maps hue angles from 0..360 (degrees) to 0..180
lower_blue = np.array([100, 64, 192])
upper_blue = np.array([120, 255, 255])
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)

skyratio = np.count_nonzero(mask) / np.size(mask)
print(f"{skyratio:.1%}")
```

Hue (0..180), Saturation, Value:
[image: HSV]

Comment: Thank you for this bit of code, I am attempting to make it work. The 72 image files themselves are in .RAW format. Will this limit the distortion of pixel information that you mentioned? The photo posted is not the actual picture file, which for this one picture was 6.6 MB.. so was too large to post directly. The other 71 photos are roughly equivalent, however with varying degrees of canopy closure. All pictures were taken on sunny days. Some may have more cloud in the background than others.

Comment: RAW is good, but also needs extra work. For your application, you _could_ shoot and "develop" all those RAW files with the same settings (ISO, exposure time, aperture, color temperature, LUTs/looks, ...) so they're comparable. -- I can't say much more without seeing some "outlier" samples. clouds do look different from clear sky, so for that my simple approach needs tweaking. it's all fairly bright though, so the biggest uncertainty isn't what the sky looks like, but how translucent leaves are counted (thresholds).